# PHP insert textarea text into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, textarea

So i was trying to echo the textarea so i know if it works but that doesnt work.
I have created a table named posts and in there you can put Id Username and post.

But it doesnt insert anything into the table heres my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$session = $_SESSION['username'];

if(!$session){
header('Location: http://wirechat.net16.net/login.php'); /* Stuur de browser naar www.site.nl */
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<title>TWITTER RAMON</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'/>
</head>
<body>
<div id='banner'>
<table style='width:100%;'>
<tr>
<td>
<span style='font-size:24px;'><b>EGGY</b></span><?php echo $session ?>
</td>
<td width='100%' style='text-align:right;'>
<a href='index.php'>Home</a> // <a href='followers.php'>Followers Post</a> // <a href='stats.php'>Stats</a> // <a href='search.php'>Search User</a> // <a href='logout.php'>logout</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div><br/><br><br/>
<div class='div' id='post'>
<table width='100%'>
<tr>
<td width='40%'>
Post je bericht:
</td>
<td width='60%'>
Afbeeldingen&Smileys
</td>
</tr>
<form action="post.php" method="POST">
<tr>
<td><textarea cols='25' name='textarea' id='textarea' class='textarea'></textarea>
</td>
<td style='padding:20 40 10 40;'>
<div style='float:left;text-align:center;'>afbeelding</div>
<div style='float:right;text-align:center;'>smileys</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class='submit'>
<tr>
<td>
<input type='submit' class='postbtn' name='post' value='Post je text!'/>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>
<div class='post'>
<table>

</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$host = "------------";
$database = "------------";
$user = "-----------";
$dbpass = "---------";

if ($postbtn){
$postbtn = $_POST['post'];
$post = $_POST['textarea'];

echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['textarea']);

//$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $dbpass);
//mysql_select_db($database, $conn);
//mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (Username, Post) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['username']."', '".$post."')", $conn);

echo "Posted successfuly!";
}
?>
```

Comment: You do realize your code for doing the insert is commented out, right? But that's a good thing because your code is wide open to a SQL injection attack.

Comment: Plus, your conditional statement (*which will never fire up*) is based on the `$postbtn` variable which isn't set nor defined. I'm guessing you're wanting to use the submit button's class name `class='postbtn'` which should be `if(isset($_POST['post'])){...}` (`name='post'`) if anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to place the *$postbtn = $_POST['post'];* line before *if ($postbtn)* as it will always result to false.

```
$postbtn = isset($_POST['post']);
if ($postbtn){
```

But be careful: As John pointed out, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection) how to prevent these.

Comment: OMG im so stupid. but how can you protect it or is that an 'other question' ?

Comment: Check this post as it answers how to prevent SQL injection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection

Answer (score 0):

this is true :

> $postbtn = isset($_POST['post']);
>
> if ($postbtn){

and so :

```
if( !empty($_POST['post']) ) {
```